# c pointers used as index of matrix

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I don't understand how are used the pointer with the matrix a.
What's happen at `*bmax = a[mm][*kp+1]`? I am not practical with pointers.

kp is an integer variable.
Here is my code:

```
double **a;
double *bmax
void allocation() {
    //...
    a = (double **) malloc((m) * sizeof(double *));
    for (i = 0; i <= m; i++)
        a[i] = (double *) malloc((n) * sizeof(double));
}
void something(double **a, int mm, int ll[], int nll, int iabf, int *kp,
        double *bmax) {
    int k;
    double test;

    if (nll <= 0)
        *bmax = 0.0;
    else {
        *kp = ll[1];
        *bmax = a[mm + 1][*kp + 1];
        for (k = 2; k <= nll; k++) {
            if (iabf == 0)
                test = a[mm + 1][ll[k] + 1] - (*bmax);
            else
                test = fabs(a[mm + 1][ll[k] + 1]) - fabs(*bmax);
            if (test > 0.0) {
                *bmax = a[mm + 1][ll[k] + 1];
                *kp = ll[k];
            }
        }
    }
}
int main(){
   int kp;
   for(;;){
              //some code
              something(a,m+1,l1,nl1,0,&kp,&bmax);
   }
}
```

Comment: @andrea  This statement *bmax=a[mm][*kp+1]; is invalid and does not make sense. Show a compiled example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Where `bmax` pointing? I see a global `bmax` and a function parameter `bmax`, but why?

Comment: `kp` is a **pointer to int**; `*kp` has a value of type `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before reading further one must be cleared with the basic concepts of the pointer, Take a look at code snippet:

```
int main() {
    int *p;  //  pointer declaration
    int a;   //  variable declaration

    a = 10;  //  Storing the value
    p = &a;  //  Storing the address of the 'a' into the memory of 'p'

    printf("%u\n",p); //  Print the value of p, address of a
    printf("%i",*p);//  Retrieve the value from the memory address saved as the value of the p, that is value of a = '10' (here)
    return 0 ;
}
```

Now,consider the line:    `*bmax = a[mm + 1][*kp + 1];`. Here, `*kp` is a **pointer to int**, which means it retrieves the integer value from the memory address stored in it. Similarly, `*bmax` is a **pointer to double**.

*Therefore*, if we evaluate the above equation then `*kp+1` is an `integer` and so is `mm+1`. Therefore, `a[integer][integer]` points to certain value *(if the indices are valid)* which will be stored to the memory `bmax` points to.